# Using TensorFlow-metal plugin, training stops after some time without any errors?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metal, apple-m1

I've followed [the steps provided by *Apple*](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/), which utilizes `conda`, to install `TensorFlow` to get the best out of the *M1 Pro MacBook Pro*. As the title is self-descriptive, the training stops after some time without any errors. Please see the `Keras` training log below. This has happened many times. What could be the reason behind this situation? Have you experienced the same on your end? If so, how can I overcome this situation?

```
...
Epoch 38/50
625/625 [==============================] - 18s 29ms/step - loss: 1.6704 - acc: 0.4178 - val_loss: 1.8169 - val_acc: 0.4044
Epoch 39/50
625/625 [==============================] - 18s 29ms/step - loss: 1.6788 - acc: 0.4157 - val_loss: 1.6830 - val_acc: 0.4029
Epoch 40/50
625/625 [==============================] - 18s 28ms/step - loss: 1.6921 - acc: 0.4089 - val_loss: 1.7088 - val_acc: 0.4049
Epoch 41/50
625/625 [==============================] - 18s 28ms/step - loss: 1.6705 - acc: 0.4170 - val_loss: 1.6650 - val_acc: 0.4182
Epoch 42/50
625/625 [==============================] - 18s 29ms/step - loss: 1.6659 - acc: 0.4177 - val_loss: 1.9102 - val_acc: 0.3443
Epoch 43/50
625/625 [==============================] - 18s 29ms/step - loss: 1.6760 - acc: 0.4166 - val_loss: 1.6647 - val_acc: 0.4222
Epoch 44/50
532/625 [========================>.....] - ETA: 2s - loss: 1.6639 - acc: 0.4217
```

Comment: Are you getting any related errors or messages in the Console app? (Utilities > Console)

Comment: No, I do not get such errors in the Console app. @JeshuaLacock